# Swift 3 use multi .swift file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, controller

Hi i need help to use multi .swift file with different View Controller in Xcode with swift 3.

Example to explain my situation, i have :

- ViewController.swift
- ViewController2.swift
- In my StoryBoard 2 view : View Controller A , View Controller B

How can i show or hide label in View Controller A from a Switch in View Controller B

ViewController.swift using for View Controller A and ViewController2.swift for View Controller B

Thx for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a var to check the state of the switch, then use the prepareforsegue function to pass over the var.
Then use an if statement to check.

```
if switchcondition == true {

  lbl.isHidden == true      

} else if switchcondition == false {

  lbl.isHidden == false

}
```

Where switchCondition is your var & lbl is your label outlet.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "segue" {
      var switchCondition = false
      //I'll keep it false by default
    }
}
```

Don't forget this:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
```

Comment: can you please tell me in detail what you don't understand?

Answer (score -1):

You can have a `static` variable in `ViewControllerA` that decides if the label is shown or not.

**ViewControllerA**

```
static var showLabel = false

func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    label.hidden = !showLabel
}
```

**ViewControllerB**

```
ViewControllerA.showLabel = true
```

Comment: Can you explain me more clearly what i have to do plz i don’t untersdant well

Comment: @ValentinCocq Basically just copy the code. The first one into your `ViewControllerA`. And the second code to where you want to change the state from. If you still don't understand, where do I have to be more clear? :)

Comment: Ok thx, i will try. PS : ViewControllerA is storyboard not .swift

Comment: I have a problem, when i change the View the switch go back to off position

Comment: Try with `switch.setOn(ViewControllerA.showLabel, animated: false)`, @ValentinCocq